# shouldDirty of 'react-hook-form' is not re-rendering the component

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have written the following code with react-hook-form. I am using material ui.
When I click the checkbox the first time(uncheck->check), everything works fine. "Comment1" appears on the page. But when I click the checkbox 2nd time(check->uncheck), the checkbox does not change state. It stays in the checked state. "Comment1" does not disappear. I am using {shouldDirty: true}. 'shouldDirty' should rerender the component with every click. Correct ?

````
  const {
    register,
    setValue,
    getValues,
    formState: { isDirty, dirtyFields },
  } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = (data: any) => {
    console.log("Data == ", data);
  };
  return (
         <>
      <FormControlLabel
        label={"First Check"}
        control={
          <Checkbox
            {...register("first")}
            onChange={(event) => {
              setValue("first", event.target.checked, {
                shouldDirty: true,
              });
            }}
            checked={!!getValues("first")}
          />
        }
      />
      {getValues("first") ? <Typography>{"Comment1"}</Typography> : <></>}
      </>
  );
};```



Thanks,
Sachin
````

Answer (score 1):

`setValue` does not trigger a re-render in most cases. From the documentation:

> Only the following conditions will trigger a re-render:
>
> When an error is triggered or corrected by a value update
>
> When setValue cause state update, such as dirty and touched.

When you click for the first time, your input becomes `dirty` so the component re-renders (and "Comment1" appears). This is not the case for second time you click because none of the two conditions above are satisfied.

If you'd like to have a consistent re-render, you might want to use `reset` method instead.

Comment: Do you have an example of how to use both dirty and reset?